# Best HttpApplication event for altering the response source

Tags: asp.net, events, response, httpmodule, httpapplication

I intend to build a `HttpModule` in order to scan a response's source and make small adjustments, mainly altering urls (`href`s, `action`s, `src`s, etc).

I see the `HttpApplication` has a plethora of events that can be handled and I'm not sure of the best stage at which it's safe to alter the HTML content that goes back to the browser.

I need to do this in a `HttpModule` because this is an application-wide processing that spares me of writing the same code in every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [response filter](http://web.archive.org/web/20141021052440/http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters) that you could attach during `BeginRequest`. And here's a [nice video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-the-reponsefilter-property-to-replace-html-in-an-aspnet-page).

Comment: That's what I was going to do (use a response filter) but I was wondering if it makes any difference over what application event I'm using for hooking it up. You say `BeginRequest`, I've seen examples using `ReleaseRequestState`.

Comment: OK, I figured that as long as you hook the filter before it's being called (no later than `ReleaseRequestState`) it doesn't matter at what step you do it.